# Embedding a view with subviews in another parent view and keeping constraints (IB)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, interface-builder, constraints

I have a scene in `storyboard` with several subviews for which I already set a lot of constraints in `Interface Builder`. These subviews are directly children of the view controller's view. Now I realize that I need the whole view + subviews be contained in a full-screen `UIScrollView` to handle scrolling of the content when the keyboard is shown. But if I simply move all the subviews inside the scroll view, I loose the constraints that referred to "superview" and I get a mess.

Is there any way to migrate the constraints regarding the previous "superview" (view controller's view) to the new parent scroll view (which is the child of the "superview")?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to do this. The constraints between the view controller's view and the subviews are as you know broken when you move your subviews into another subview/view. AFIAK the biggest reason for this is you could end up with subviews that have constraints which relate to views on longer in their
 view hierarchy which is a violate of the constraints lay out system.